# Issue where worker is not receiving `canvas` message when using NextJS (react)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html5-canvas, web-worker

I have a React Class component `AudioVisualizer` which is meant to take a `MediaStream` and display a visualizer of the audio on a canvas that's controlled by a worker. However I have an issue where the canvas is not being updated and after some debugging it looks like the worker is not receiving the `canvas` message, but I don't understand why. I far as I can see everything should work.

#### `AudioVisualizer` component

```tsx
import { createRef, RefObject, Component } from "react";

type AudioAnalyserConfig = {
    fftSize?: number,
    smoothingTimeConstant?: number,
    minDecibels?: number,
    maxDecibels?: number
};

interface AudioVisualizerProps {
    stream: MediaStream,
    config?: AudioAnalyserConfig
}


export class AudioVisualizer extends Component<AudioVisualizerProps> {
    stream: MediaStream;
    config?: AudioAnalyserConfig;
    audioContext?: AudioContext;
    analyser?: AnalyserNode;
    canvas?: HTMLCanvasElement;
    bufferLength?: number;
    dataArray: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array();
    source?: MediaStreamAudioSourceNode;
    worker?: Worker;
    offscreenCanvas = false;

    constructor(props: AudioVisualizerProps) {
        super(props)
        this.stream = props.stream;
        this.config = props.config;

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
        this.setAnalyser();
        this.setSource();
        this.worker = new Worker(new URL('../worker.ts', import.meta.url));

        if (!this.canvas) throw Error('No canvas');
        if (!this.offscreenCanvas && this.worker) {
            console.log(this.worker);
            const canvas = this.canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
            this.worker.postMessage({ type: 'canvas', canvas }, [canvas]);
            this.offscreenCanvas = true;
        }

        this.animate();
    }

    componentWillUnmount(): void {
        if (this.worker) {
            this.worker.terminate();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <canvas ref={this.setCanvasRef} ></canvas>
    }

    private setCanvasRef = (element: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
        this.canvas = element;
    }

    private setSource() {
        if (!this.audioContext) throw Error("No Audio Context");
        if (!this.analyser) throw Error("No Analyser");

        this.source = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(this.stream);
        this.source.connect(this.analyser)
    }

    private setAnalyser() {
        if (!this.audioContext) throw Error('No Audio Context');
        if (!this.canvas) throw Error('No Current on Canvas Ref');

        this.analyser = this.audioContext.createAnalyser();
        this.bufferLength = this.analyser.frequencyBinCount;
        this.dataArray = new Uint8Array(this.bufferLength);

        if (!this.config) return;
        this.analyser.fftSize = this.config.fftSize || 2048;
        this.analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = this.config.smoothingTimeConstant || 0.8;
        this.analyser.minDecibels = this.config.minDecibels || -100;
        this.analyser.maxDecibels = this.config.maxDecibels || -30;
    }

    animate = () => {
        if (!this.analyser) throw Error("No Analyser");
        if (!this.worker) throw Error('No worker');

        this.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(this.dataArray);
        this.worker.postMessage({ type: 'frame', bufferLength: this.bufferLength, dataArray: this.dataArray }, {});
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    };
}
```

#### `worker.ts`

```ts
let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement | null = null;


const drawVisualizer = ({ bufferLength, dataArray }: { bufferLength: number, dataArray: any[] }) => {
    if (!canvas) return;
    let barHeight;
    const barWidth = canvas.width / 2 / bufferLength;
    let firstX = 0;
    let secondX = bufferLength * barWidth;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    if (!ctx) return;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        barHeight = dataArray[i];
        const red = (i * barHeight) / 10;
        const green = i * 4;
        const blue = barHeight / 4 - 12;
        ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
        ctx.fillRect(
            canvas.width / 2 - firstX,
            canvas.height - barHeight,
            barWidth,
            barHeight
        );
        firstX += barWidth;
        ctx.fillRect(secondX, canvas.height - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
        secondX += barWidth;
    }
};

addEventListener('message', e => {
    // console.log("Worker: Message received from main script");
    const { type, bufferLength, dataArray, canvas: canvasMessage } = e.data;
    console.log(type); // only `frame` prints
    switch (type) {
        case 'canvas':
            canvas = canvasMessage;
            break;
        case 'frame':
            drawVisualizer({ bufferLength, dataArray });
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});

export { }
```

Comment: What kind of debugging did you do to come to that conclusion? I'm not really into reactjs, but one thing I see often around here is that the component get rerendered, and the element's reference you had in your method isn't the one in the DOM anymore. Does that ring a bell to you in that situation? Otherwise, from a plain JS point of view, indeed, it seems that should work. One thing you could try for debugging is to remove the Worker and execute the rendering code from the same thread.

Comment: @Kaiido the main thing i did was check the messages the worker received. it currently logs the value of `type` and that should be`canvas` for the canvas message but that is never logged. It losing the ref of the canvas element could be happen i suppose but i'm get the ref in a correct way, i should probably use `createRef()` instead tho as it's the new way.

Comment: I ended up working around the issue by not using a web worker. May revisit this in the future.